# Tensorflow 2 multiple simultaneous predictions

Tags: python, tensorflow, multiprocessing, tensorflow2.0

In Tensorflow 2 after loading saved model with 
`tf.saved_model.load(my_model)` How can I run multiple predictions with same model( not Graph)?

I am using Pool class from multiprocessing package. Importing tensorflow and keras in helper method before loading model did not help:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
tf.saved_model.load(my_model)
```

Error code:

> Can't pickle local object 'Loader._recreate_base_user_object.._UserObject'

Comment: TF2.0 has no Graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was suggested in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53979199/tensorflow-keras-returning-multiple-predictions-while-expecting-one), passing multiple inputs in array (numpy or python doesn't matter) works better than for loop. Performance improvement was 25%. 
Don't forget to set thread number:

```
tf.config.threading.set_intra_op_parallelism_threads(num_cores)
tf.config.threading.set_inter_op_parallelism_threads(num_cores)
```

*However should note that tensorflow would use number of thread times more memory.*